# How can I set my published sheet to publish in black and white?

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to publish a data sheet that pulls values from a server, assembles them into a data sheet, publishes an mhtml copy of that sheet as an accessible record before distributing that data to another sheet and clearing the original sheet. I have every part of this working, but I would like to give our operators the option to print the mhtml copy saved on our drive if necessary. Thus, I would like to publish the mhtml copy in black and white.

```
With ActiveWorkbook.PublishObjects.Add(xlSourceSheet, "html storage files", "Sheet name", "", xlHtmlStatic, "", "")
    .Publish (True)
    .AutoRepublish = False
    ? .HtmlType  ?
End With
```

Comment: Have you tried this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pagesetup.blackandwhite

Comment: is saving as pdf an option? (with link of L8n)